# Get week number in a quarter in java

Tags: java, date

I am trying to get the week number from a date within a quarter.

From the below I can get the week number of the year but not within the quarter.

```
String input = "20130805";
String format = "yyyyMMdd";

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = df.parse(input);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

The result should be week number of 3rd quarter

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you define "week of quarter"? Is the first week of a quarter the week containing the first day of the first month of the quarter or is it maybe the first week that has minimum 4 days of the quarter or similar?

Comment: `week = week % 13;` ?

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`.  You should instead use the appropriate class in the `java.time` package.

Comment: You need to define your terms. How do you define a week and week-of-year? Do you mean standard ISO 8601 weeks? Or some other week?  How do you define a quarter?

Comment: No doubt it can be done, either you can use the classes in `java.time` (introduced in Java 8 and largely backported to 6 and 7) or you are left with the older and often more challenging `Date` and `Calendar`. If we’re to inspire, you need to be clear about how you count weeks within the quarter and which day the week begins (Sunday, Monday or first day of the quarter, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Doing a modulo will bring you the answer:

```
int x = 52 / 4; //52 week as ave in a year
System.out.println(week);
System.out.println("you are in the quartal number: " + (week / x + 1));
System.out.println("this is the week number: " + week % x + " in the quartal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String input = "20130805";
String format = "yyyyMMdd";

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = df.parse(input);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int weekForYear = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int previousQuarter = (date.getMonth() / 3);

System.out.println("No. of weeks for current Quarter: " + weekForYear - (previousQuarter*13));
```